# Mocha test results in browser shows blank

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to do unit testing with Mocha and Chai. The test runs successfully in terminal, but when I check the testrunner.html file in browser it is blank and just shows "passes: 0failures: 0duration: 0s"

But in terminal it shows:

```
$ mocha

  Array
    ✓ should start empty

  1 passing (18ms)
```

Comment: I posted a solution for you below. Did it work?

Comment: It worked for the code you provided. But didn't work for my test

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

*In this order in your HTML*

1. Link to a mocha css stylesheet.

   ```html
   <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   ```

   ---
2. Write a `div` tag with `id='mocha'`. The tests will be inserted in this `div`, which will allow you to see them in the browser.

   ```html
   <div id="mocha"></div>
   ```

   ---
3. Write a script tag to load mocha.

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>
   ```

   ---
4. Write a script tag to load any other dependencies like `chai`.

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.1.0/chai.js"></script>
   ```

   ---
5. Setup the mocha BDD api (or TDD depending on how you are writing your tests).

   ```html
    <script>mocha.setup("bdd");</script>
   ```

   ---
6. Write your test (inline or link to an external JavaScript file).

   BDD example:

   ```js
   describe("addition", function() {
     it("adds 1 and 1", function() {
       expect(1 + 1).to.equal(2);
     });
   });
   ```

   ---
7. Run Mocha.

   ```js
   mocha.run();
   ```

---

**Snippet Example**

*Try running this snippet*

```html
<!-- link to mocha css stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--  write a div with id "mocha" for the output to be inserted into -->
<div id="mocha"></div>

<!-- load mocha framework -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>

<!-- load any other libraries like the chai assertion library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.1.0/chai.js"></script>


<!-- setup mocha to use the BDD interface -->
<!-- Note: you can use TDD here instead -->
<!-- depending on how you are writing your tests -->
<!-- more information: http://mochajs.org/#tdd -->
<script>
  mocha.setup("bdd");
</script>

<!-- write tests -->
<script>
  // access 'expect' from chai
  var expect = chai.expect;

  // write tests (BDD example)
  describe("addition", function() {
    it("adds 1 and 1", function() {
      expect(1 + 1).to.equal(2);
    });
    it("adds 1000 and 10", function() {
      expect(1000 + 10).to.equal(1010);
    });    
  });
  describe("subtraction", function() {
    it("subtracts 1 from 1", function() {
      expect(1 - 1).to.equal(0);
    });
    it("subtracts 10 from 1000", function() {
      expect(1000 - 10).to.equal(990);
    });    
  });
  describe("multiplication", function() {
    it("multiplies 1 by 1", function() {
      expect(1 * 1).to.equal(1);
    });
    it("multiplies 1000 by 10", function() {
      expect(1000 * 10).to.equal(10000);
    });    
  });
  describe("division", function() {
    it("divides 1 by 1", function() {
      expect(1 / 1).to.equal(1);
    });
    it("divides 1000 by 10", function() {
      expect(1000 / 10).to.equal(100);
    });    
  });    
</script>

<!-- run mocha -->
<script>
  mocha.run();
</script>
```

---

**Demo**

- Here is a [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/brwqeQ) that does not use so much inline JavaScript.

---

**Documentation**

- Useful information can be found [here](http://mochajs.org/#browser-specific-methods) at the official documentation.